# Canvas drawing in HTML element is not showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I have a Chrome extension that I wrote some time ago. One of the functions in it was that it would draw a background of HTML element using `document.getCSSCanvasContext`. But evidently Google deprecated that function, so my drawing method doesn't work anymore. Unfortunately it's been a while since I wrote it to see how to replace it correctly. So far, I've done this.

HTML goes as such:

```
    <div id="idStrgUsg">
        <canvas id="idSmplCvs" width="453" height="1"></canvas>
        <div id="idStrgUsgBar"></div>
    </div>
```

and then the JS:

```
    var perc = 75;

    //Get width of the fill bar
    var objFill = $("#idStrgUsgBar");
    var objParFill = objFill.parent();
    var w = objParFill.outerWidth();
    var h = objParFill.outerHeight();

    var w_f = w * perc / 100;

    var cnvs = document.getElementById("idSmplCvs");
    cnvs.width = w;
    cnvs.height = h;

    var ctx = cnvs.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(193,139,96)";

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w_f, h);

    objFill.text(perc.toFixed(1) + "%");
```

But it doesn't fill it with anything:

[image]

So what am I missing there?

Comment: Position the canvas absolutely into the div.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to define the height and width for the parent element. Log the value of h and w and see what you are getting. Perhaps refer https://jsfiddle.net/o4smqpLr/

```
<div id="idStrgUsg" style="width:100px; height: 10px">
        <canvas id="idSmplCvs" width="453" height="10"></canvas>
        <div id="idStrgUsgBar"></div>
    </div>

var perc = 75;

    //Get width of the fill bar
    var objFill = document.getElementById("idStrgUsgBar");
    var objParFill = objFill.parentElement;
    console.log(objParFill.style);
    var w = parseInt(objParFill.style.width);
    var h = parseInt(objParFill.style.height);
        console.log(w);
    console.log(h);
    var w_f = w * perc / 100;

    var cnvs = document.getElementById("idSmplCvs");
    cnvs.width = w;
    cnvs.height = h;

    var ctx = cnvs.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(193,139,96)";

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w_f, h);
        //ctx.stroke();
    objFill.innerHTML = perc.toFixed(1) + "%";
```